# WooCommerce check if product attribute has value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to amend an existing Woo code snippet to change how prices are displayed. I need to display certain text if a certain attribute is present on a variable product.

I thought this might work >

```
$my_terms = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_pricing');

    if (in_array('rent', $my_terms)) {$price_text = sprintf('%s: ', __('is rental', 'wcvp_range'));} else {$price_text = sprintf('%s: ', __('no rental here', 'wcvp_range'));};
```

Or maybe this

```
if ( has_term( 'Rent', 'pa_pricing' )) {$price_text = sprintf('%s: ', __('is rental', 'wcvp_range'));} else {$price_text = sprintf('%s: ', __('no rental here', 'wcvp_range'));};
```

Neither of the above work....

It's to sit insde this code (in functions.php) and to eventually replace the text in $wcv_price if the word 'Rent' is not found as a price attribute. I'm obviously not a php genius.... :)

```
function wc_varb_price_range( $wcv_price, $product ) {
 
    $prefix = sprintf('%s: ', __('Rent from', 'wcvp_range'));
 
    $wcv_reg_min_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
    $wcv_reg_max_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true );
    $wcv_min_sale_price    = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );
    $wcv_max_sale_price    = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'max', true );
    $wcv_max_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true );
    $wcv_min_price = $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true );

    $wcv_price = ( $wcv_min_sale_price == $wcv_reg_min_price ) ?
        wc_price( $wcv_reg_min_price ) :
        '<del>' . wc_price( $wcv_reg_min_price ) . '</del>' . '<ins>' . wc_price( $wcv_min_sale_price ) . '</ins>';
        
    $wcv_bo_price = ( $wcv_max_sale_price == $wcv_reg_max_price ) ?
        wc_price( $wcv_reg_max_price ) :
        '<del>' . wc_price( $wcv_reg_max_price ) . '</del>' . '<ins>' . wc_price( $wcv_max_sale_price ) . '</ins>';    
 
    return ( $wcv_min_price == $wcv_max_price ) ?
        $wcv_price :
        sprintf('%s%s', $prefix, $wcv_price)." per month <br> Buy for <span class='woocommerce-Price-amount amount'>".$wcv_bo_price."</span>";

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'wc_varb_price_range', 10, 2 ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'wc_varb_price_range', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: `get_the_terms` does not return an array of plain text strings, it returns an array of `WP_Term` instances - so you can not just use `in_array('rent', $my_terms)`, and hope that would find anything in there. The `name` property of `WP_Term` is of public visibility though, so you should be able to extract the names from this array using `array_column`, to get an array that contains _only_ the names in string form, so that you can then go search inside that with `in_array`. (Or `slug` instead of name, whichever you want to use as identifier.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of a product attribute, you can use the `get_attribute()` method on the product class.

Example:

```
$pricing = $product->get_attribute( 'pricing' );
```

This method will return a string.

Where this gets slightly more complicated is when you potentially have multiple values for a given attribute. `get_attribute()` will return a comma delimited string of values. In that case, you'd need to convert it back into an array.

Example:

```
$pricing = explode( ', ', $product->get_attribute( 'pricing' ) );
```

Full version of check:

```
// If you know that 'pricing' will only ever be a single value.
if ( 'rent' == $product->get_attribute( 'pricing' ) ) {
  // . . .


// If you believe that the pricing attribute may have multiple values.
$pricing = explode( ', ', $product->get_attribute( 'pricing' ) );

if ( in_array( 'rent', $pricing ) ) {
    // . . .
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, couldn't get your code to work, not completely sure how arrays work (I wasn't joking about not being a genius!) but I have an idea what a string is.

So searched the string instead and it worked! 


$pricing = $product->get_attribute( 'pricing' ) ;

if (strpos($pricing, 'rent' ) )  {

Comment: As you can see, I'm also unable to format comments...

Comment: @Mark__Thomas Can you do a `var_dump` on $pricing for me please? I'd like to make sure this answer benefits anyone facing a similar issue so I'll revise it accordingly.

Comment: Non php wizz doesn't know what a var dump is, but if I echo $pricing on the product page I get 'Buy Now, Rent Now', which is a comma delimited string of the two price attributes for that product. Does that help?

Comment: @Mark__Thomas The reason you ran into a problem is because your attribute value isn't "rent", it's "Rent Now". If you took the array example, you'd end up with an array like this: `['Buy Now', 'Rent Now']`. The check would therefore be `if ( in_array( 'Rent Now', $pricing ) ) {...`

Comment: Oops, didn't realise that it had to be an exact match! That'll be why I spent the entire day failing... Is there any performance difference between using array or searching the string? Will mark your answer as correct, thank you.

Comment: No problem :) I wouldn't give a second thought to the performance difference between the two. There are any number of ways you can shoot yourself in the foot performance-wise but this would be bottom of the list. You're better off writing it the way that can be most easily understood. The array approach uses an exact match and avoids issues that can creep in with similar names for instance.